# Running sed on a large (30G) one-line file returns an empty output

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, command-line

I'm trying to perform simple literal search/replace on a large (30G) **one-line** file, using `sed`.

I would expect this to take some time but, when I run it, it returns after a few seconds and, when I look at the generated file, it's zero length.

- input file has 30G

  ```
  $ ls -lha Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line.txt  
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 30G Jun  9 19:51 Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line.txt
  ```
- run the command:

  ```
  $ sed 's/<unk>/ /g' Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line.txt > Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line-No-unks.txt
  ```
- the output file has zero length!

  ```
  $ ls -lha Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line-No-unks.txt 
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jun  9 19:52 Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line-No-unks.txt
  ```

**Things I've tried**

- running the very same example on a shorter file: **works**
- using -e modifier: **doesn't work**
- escaping "<" and ">": **doesn't work**
- using a simple pattern line (`'s/foo/bar/g'`) instead: **doesn't work**: zero-length file is returned.

### EDIT (more information)

- return code is **0**
- sed version is **(GNU sed) 4.2.2**

Comment: What is the exit status? Does it indicate success?

Comment: with that format you have difficulty using line-based editors.  There is no way `sed` can keep that 30G line in memory for processing.

Comment: @karakfa but doesn't it read the file in stream-like fashion? I mean, only small chunks at a time?

Comment: please provide your sed version `sed --version`

Comment: @karakfa return code is **0**

Comment: @Ramast **sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2**

Comment: suggestion, try `fold -s longline` which will break into lines around spaces around 80 columns each. if you don't have whitespace, remove the `-s` but you have to check the pattern if it breaks into two lines.  After replacement you can unfold it back by removing new lines.

Comment: the only issue with that suggestion is that some of the "<unk>" text will be split between two lines and won't be replaced.

Comment: Are there any delimiters in this file?  If not, how do you even plan to parse it back?

Comment: @karakfa yes, there are. It's a single line with space-separated tokens (words).

Comment: OK then, `fold -s` might work...

Comment: @karakfa I'm trying it now... so far so good (do write an answer so I can tick you if it works =))

Comment: Maybe 
    split
is worth a try.

Comment: This sounds like the Out-Of-Memory Killer kills your program while reading the 30G (check your system log). Sed probably wants to read a complete line first, before it starts working on the pattern (e.g. a $ anchor and many other patterns would always require this). That's why you get a zero length file.

Comment: And why the hell do you have a program that creates 30G one liners? Fix that program to produce something sensible.

Comment: After inding a char not in the `<unk>`, you can try `tr 'e' '\n' << Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line.txt | sed 's/<unk>/ /g' | tr '\n' 'e' > Full-Text-Tokenized-Single-Line-No-unks.txt`.

Comment: @Jens haha I created the file myself... I'm using it to build a language model and this particular tool I'm using requires the file to be in this form.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida `sed` reads a file line by line, because its entire execution model is based on applying patterns to a single line; usually a line *is* a small chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with line-based editors like `sed` you can't expect this to work, since its unit of work (record) is the line terminated with line breaks.

One suggestion if you have white space in your file (to prevent searched pattern to split) is use

```
fold -s file_with_one_long_line | 
sed 's/find/replace/g'          | 
tr -d '\n' > output
```

**ps.** `fold` default width is 80, in case you have words longer than 80 you can add `-w 1000` or at least the longest word size to prevent word splitting.

Comment: the data in question is list of word tokens, most likely length of words will be less than 80 (dictionary words are less than 45 chars).  However, in case of made up words for longer lengths `fold` has `-w` flag to set the width to, perhaps 1000.  I will add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use awk, it's designed for handling records separated by arbitrary strings. With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='<unk>' '{ORS=(RT?" ":"")}1' file
```

The above splits the input into records separated by `<unk>` so if enough `<unk>`s are present in the input then the individual records will be small enough to fit in memory. It then prints each record followed by a blank char so the overall impact to the data is that all `<unk>`s become blank chars.

If that direct approach doesn't work for you THEN it'd be time to start looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: This will crash if the match is further into the file than the amount of memory available or if there isn't a match.

Answer (score 2):

Officially gnu sed has no line limit
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq6_005.html
However the page state that:

> "no limit" means there is no "fixed" limit. Limits are actually determined by one's hardware, memory, operating system, and which C library is used to compile sed.

I tried running sed on a 7gb single file could reproduce same issue.
This page https://community.hpe.com/t5/Languages-and-Scripting/Sed-Maximum-Line-Length/td-p/5136721 suggest using perl instead

```
perl -pe 's/start=//g;s/stop=//g;s/<unk>/ /g' file > output
```

Comment: `Out of memory!` Unfortunately!

Comment: well, the whole line has to be read in order to properly perform the replace operation. your best option is adding 30G+ swap partition

Comment: if your intention is to just perform simple find and replace operation, I am sure a simple program can be written to read one character at a time, when character is found to be `<` then read the next 4 letters, if they were `unk>` then echo back blank space ` `

Comment: The `start=` and `stop=` parts were specific to the file used by the OP in the posted link; they aren't appropriate here.

Comment: If you tell me the updated command, I'll update the post and mention you.
I have no perl programming skills

Answer (score 2):

If the tokens are space(not all whitespace) delimited and assuming your are only matching single words then you could use perl with space as the record separator

```
perl -040 -pe 's/<unk>/ /' file
```

or GNU awk to match all whitespace

```
awk -vRS="[[:space:]]" '{ORS=RT;sub(/<unk>/," ")} file
```

Comment: @123 is that one or more spaces or just a single one?

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida A single one, but in the context of only matching single words, it wouldn't make any difference, it would just be like blank lines in a file.